# IPC call to service causes NullPointerException when called from main thread but not on button event

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl

I'm trying  to create a service with an IPC connection defined in an .aidl file.

The service starts and the service connection can bind to it, but when the IPC API is called from the same thread it causes a `NullPointerException`. 
When the call to the IPC API is put in an event on a button press it works.

How can this be fixed so that the call can be done without having a button event to start it.

My MainActivicty

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public final String TAG = "Main Activity";
        IMyAidlInterface iMyAidlInterface;
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                iMyAidlInterface = IMyAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                iMyAidlInterface = null;
            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Intent interFaceServiceIntent = new Intent(this, IMyAidlService.class);
            bindService(interFaceServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            Intent sigGenIntent = new Intent(this, signalGenerator.class);
            startService(sigGenIntent);

            Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);

/*
* The following block is what I want to be able to execute. Currently it causes * a NullPointerException 
* Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method * 'int com.aidltest.IMyAidlInterface.getPid()' on a null object reference
*/
            try {
                iMyAidlInterface.getPid();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
/*
*  The block below using the same interface from within a button event works
*   without problem.
*/

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        iMyAidlInterface.getPid();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

For reference my Aidl:

```
package com.aidltest;
interface IMyAidlInterface {
    int getPid();
    void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
            double aDouble, String aString);
}
```

And my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aidltest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".IMyAidlService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `iMyAidlInterface` is `null` in your `onCreate` call. It is not set until your connection listener calls you back via `onServiceConnected`. Binding is an async operation.

Comment: How should/could this be resolved? The sluggish solution I did by adding 
´while (iMyAidlInterface==null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for connection.");
        }´
Did not result in anything but an infinite loop. So from that it seems like it is done in the same  thread.

Comment: I assume that what I want to do is to wait until the service is started. But putting a Thread.sleep or check loop in the main thread seems not to solve the problem.

Comment: It's asynchronous, so you need to make your code event driven. You cannot make a call to the service until after `onServiceConnected` is executed.  You could have it send a message or `Runnable` to a `Handler` or something similar to this.  Be careful making calls to services on your main thread, they are *blocking* calls and can cause ANR if your service call takes too long.